# Cannot create an instance of an abstract class error when using random in Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, abstract-class

I am currently following an Udacity course and the task is to create an app that rolls dice. When I try to use Random() I get this error "Cannot create an instance of an abstract class"

I've already tried to ask the maker of the course and she hasn't responded yet so I'm trying this because I'm impatient

```
    val resultText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.result_text)

    val randomInt = Random().nextInt(6)+1

    resultText.text = randomInt.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Random](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html) is an abstract class. Its companion object is the default implementation. All you need is

```
val randomInt = Random.nextInt(6) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today which then led me to this question. I resolved it myself while exploring the videos.

The issue is not with [Random](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html) abstract class. Your code is absolutely right. However, you need to add `import java.util.*` at the top of your **MainActivity.kt** file. This imports all of the java utilities to run Kotlin's classes including **Random** class.

I hope this helps.